# How do i go about uploading full PDF files into my PARSE backend?

Tags: json, csv, pdf, parse-platform, xcode6

i am currently in the process of creating a sort of magazine/blog application in Xcode 6 for iOS, and I'm curious about how to go about actually uploading full PDF'd articles into PARSE in a way that users can touch the thumbnail of the article in the app & the server goes and fetches the PDF'd article from he cloud. I understand parse supports JSON and CSV so how do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user is the one uploading files all you have to do is use `PFFile` and `saveInBackground:` I'm assuming PFFile since you tagged xcode6. If your not using obj c then use swifts equivalent. It's simple really. Nothing that doesn't have an answer already on thousands of SO questions or various other websites. If your the one uploading the file just do it from the console unless you want to do it with a mobile device, then you'll simply use the same syntax as stated above.

Downloading or showing them is just the opposite. Still simple, you'll just perform a query to retrieve the object. Your question is too broad right now, however that answers the question. You will have to put some research and effort into trying things first before you post a question, this eliminates potential answers being submitted that doesn't apply to you or your circumstances.

Comment: no the user isn't uploading anything. my question was only referring to me uploading a full pdf file to my parse backend, so it can load as soon as the user taps a thumbnail of the article within the app. if that makes sense. I have the pdf files on my mac, just need to know how to upload them to my cloud.

Comment: If it's on your Mac and you want to upload it from the website all you have to do is create a PFFile column type and double click its corresponding row index @RobertTillman but my answer covers all scenarios because you weren't that specific